# Error: sendmsg() to UDP should not be -1 while executing a TCL script (using NS & NAM)

Tags: tcp, null, udp, tcl, ns2

I'm writing a script in TCL using NS and NAM.

What is the statement question I'm trying to solve? Here it is:

[image: Question]

Following is the TCL script I have written to solve the above problem. I'm using NS2 and NAM packages in Ubuntu 20.04. I'm tasked to create 8 nodes, link them using duplex-link (of any capacity), apply TCP Agent on node 0 & 1 and apply UDP on node 2.

Then, I need to connect the TCP Agent(s) with CBR source and UDP agent with FTP source. Following is my code:

```
set val(stop)   10.0;


set ns [new Simulator]

#Open the NS trace file
set tracefile [open out.tr w]
$ns trace-all $tracefile

#Open the NAM trace file
set namfile [open out.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $namfile

#===================================
#        Nodes Definition        
#===================================
#Create 8 nodes
set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]
set n3 [$ns node]
set n4 [$ns node]
set n5 [$ns node]
set n6 [$ns node]
set n7 [$ns node]

$ns duplex-link $n0 $n3 20.0Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n3 20.0Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n3 $n2 20.0Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n3 $n4 20.0Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n4 $n6 20.0Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n4 $n5 20.0Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n4 $n7 20.0Mb 10ms DropTail

$ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n3 orient right-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n1 $n3 orient right
$ns duplex-link-op $n3 $n2 orient left-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n3 $n4 orient right
$ns duplex-link-op $n4 $n6 orient right
$ns duplex-link-op $n4 $n5 orient right-up
$ns duplex-link-op $n4 $n7 orient right-down

#===================================
#        Agents Definition        
#===================================

set tcp [new Agent/TCP]
$ns attach-agent $n0 $tcp
$ns attach-agent $n1 $tcp

set udp [new Agent/UDP]
$ns attach-agent $n2 $udp

set cbr [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr attach-agent $tcp
$cbr set packet_size_ 1500

set ftp [new Application/FTP]
$ftp attach-agent $udp
$ftp set type_ FTP

# null & sink

set null [new Agent/Null]
$ns attach-agent $n6 $null
$ns connect $udp $null

set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
$ns attach-agent $n6 $sink
$ns connect $tcp $sink


proc finish {} {
    global ns tracefile namfile
    $ns flush-trace
    close $tracefile
    close $namfile
    exec nam out.nam &
    exit 0
}

$ns at 0.5 "$ftp start"
$ns at 5.0 "$ftp stop"

$ns at 6.0 "finish"
$ns run
```

When I run this code using `ns file.tcl` - I get the following error:

```
 Error:  sendmsg() for UDP should not be -1
ns: _o180 stop: 
    (_o177 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o177 cmd advance 0"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o177" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"[$self agent] advance 0"
    (procedure "_o180" line 2)
    (Application/FTP stop line 2)
    invoked from within
"_o180 stop"
```

Comment: What was the value of `errno` when you got the -1 return? And where is the *code?*

Comment: I have already attached the code in the question, just look below the "Following is the code" line. And how do I check errno's value? I'm new to NS/NAM/TCL, which explains my confusion..

Comment: ?Could be a wrong sequence of terms / commands ? .... Please try out two similar examples which are running OK → https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LCQPDTgijztMFt4J2SMRSHu6x5DkFhoi?usp=sharing → 1_8node_tcp.tcl, 2_8node_tcp.tcl . ...... All ~3000 ns2 ex https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?resourcekey=0-vrEMHtGTFP3yLoTQz_UAwA&usp=sharing

Comment: With that error message, it looks like the C level code is throwing away the cause of the error. Or maybe isn't expecting an error to occur at all (a bad plan for any OS API call). It isn't coming from standard Tcl code, so there isn't much I can really advise other than to look for code that calls `sendmsg()` *in C*.